# How to access property of object within ng-table ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I want to access the 'event' clicked on within the `ng-repeat` of an `ng-table`, but I can't figure out how to access this specific 'event' (the index of 'events') within my controller.

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<table ng-table="events.tableParams">
  <tr ng-repeat="event in $data">
    <td>{{event.state}}</td>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="option in event.options">
          <a href="" ng-click="events.performAction(option.value, event.id, option.type)">{{option.label}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

...and the relevant section of my controller:

```
vm.performAction = function(action, id, type) {
  if (action === 'cancel') {
    event.state = 'canceling';
  }
};
```

`event.state` within this controller code is obviously incorrect but highlights what I'm trying to update within my HTML.

Comment: In this line: `<a href="" ng-click="events.performAction(option.value, event.id, option.type)">`, I thought it should be `event`, not `events`?

Comment: `events` is my `$scope` object. I use the `controllerAs` syntax. So `events.performAction()` is correct as it's attached to the scope.

Comment: Instead of passing `event.id` to performAction, just pass `event` itself, then you'll be able to modify it as needed.  (But name it something less confusing please! :)

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the `event.state = 'canceling';` is incorrect in your controller.  From your question, it looks as if you are trying to make an update to `<td>{{event.state}}</td>` when the user clicks on the list.

The `<td>{{event.state}}</td>` is binded to $data as dictated by `<tr ng-repeat="event in $data">` which in turn is binded to `events.tableParams`.  Therefore, in your controller, you should be updating the `$scope.events.tableParams.state`.